# When I copy data from Qt-Creator to Excel, the tabs are turned into spaces

Tags: microsoft-excel, encoding, qt

I am using Qt-Creator to edit a file which contains lines of tab delineated data, and I have white-space rendering turned on in Qt-Creator, so I can see the tabs. When I copy this data into an excel spreadsheet, it only copies into one column, and the data in excel actually contains four spaces, rather than tabs.

Copying the same data to Sticky Notes retains the tabs.

I would just use "text to columns" however some of my data contains spaces.

If I copy the data to Sticky Notes, then into Excel, Excel picks up the tabs correctly.

Thus I believe Qt is encoding them weirdly, but I'm not sure how to prove that.

I'm looking for a setting in Qt which will prevent this from happening, or I'll raise a bug report if this isn't intentional.

Comment: Paste as TEXT first?

Comment: If I select `paste->special->text` it works as expected, could the text from QtCreator be detected as HTML?

Comment: `paste->special->text` does not do what we need:it copies everything verbatim _into one cell_